# Sum A Column Using Unique Groups Of Time Periods

Tags: mariadb, group-by

I have data that looks like this:

```
name      |sides|start     |end       
----------+-----+----------+----------
STR00248  |2    |2021-01-04|          
STR00250  |1    |2021-01-04|          
STR00246  |1    |2021-03-29|2021-09-12
STR00247  |1    |2021-03-29|2021-04-25
STR00248  |2    |2021-03-29|2021-09-12
STR00247  |1    |2021-03-29|2021-09-12
STR00248  |2    |2021-05-11|2021-08-10
STR00250  |1    |2021-05-24|2021-11-07
STR00250  |1    |2021-07-01|          
STR00250  |1    |2021-07-19|2022-06-19
```

I want to get the sum of `sides` for `STR00250` grouped by unique combinations of `start` and `end`. If `end` is NULL, it should be considered not to end. So the result should look something like this:

```
sum
---
1 (2021-01-04 - 2021-05-23)
2 (2021-05-24 - 2021-06-30)
3 (2021-07-01 - 2021-07-18)
4 (2021-07-19 - 2022-06-18)
3 (2022-06-19 - 2021-11-07)
2 (2021-11-08 - forward)
```

I don't need the dates, just the sums, although it would be nice to have the dates for error message purposes (in which case they should be in a separate column). Unfortunately browsing StackExchange hasn't triggered any ideas on how to accomplish my goal.

Here is the table structure and some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
`name` VARCHAR(140),
`sides` INT(11),
`start` DATE,
`end` DATE
);
```

```
INSERT INTO sample VALUES
('STR00248', 2, '2021-01-04', NULL),
('STR00250', 1, '2021-01-04', NULL),
('STR00246', 1, '2021-03-29', '2021-09-12'),
('STR00247', 1, '2021-03-29', '2021-04-25'),
('STR00248', 2, '2021-03-29', '2021-09-12'),
('STR00247', 1, '2021-03-29', '2021-09-12'),
('STR00248', 2, '2021-05-11', '2021-08-10'),
('STR00250', 1, '2021-05-24', '2021-11-07'),
('STR00250', 1, '2021-07-01', NULL),
('STR00250', 1, '2021-07-19', '2022-06-19');
```

Comment: For `end` dates that are `NULL`, is that equivalent to `9999-12-31`?  (i.e. the syntactic end of time) or is it inferred to be the day before the next start date or something?

Comment: It is equivalent to 9999-12-31, yes; i.e. there is no end date.

Comment: I really don;t understand where the expected results come from. `STR00250` only has 4 rows which sum up to 4, and most of your end dates don't exist in the table. `2022-06-19 - 2021-11-07` doesn't make sense as start and end dates, and also aren't in the table. Please explain the logic you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Charlieface I'm looking for SUM(sides) based on timespans between the first start and the last end. Each row of the result is defined by unique SUM(sides) + timespan combinations in order of time.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be your expected results: for example how does `2022-06-19 - 2021-11-07` make sense, and how does `2022-06-19` become a start and not an end? You also say "*grouped by unique combinations of start and end*" what does unique combinations mean here? Please detail the logic, it's really unclear

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```sql
WITH 
-- gathering all mentioned dates with ther weights
cte1 AS ( SELECT name, sides, start dt, 1 weight
          FROM sample
          UNION ALL
          SELECT name, sides, `end`, -1
          FROM sample ),
-- calculating the cumulative sum for each date
cte2 AS ( SELECT DISTINCT
                 name, 
                 dt, 
                 SUM(sides * weight) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY dt IS NULL, dt) cum
          FROM cte1 )
-- add period end date, remove excess (NULL) rows
SELECT name, 
       dt start,
       LEAD(dt) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY dt IS NULL, dt) - INTERVAL 1 DAY `end`,
       cum `sum`
FROM cte2
HAVING start IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY name, dt IS NULL, dt;
```

If you need the info for separate `name` then add according `WHERE` to each subquery in `cte1`.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=46a3202548714c17dc553b43d1fa5ccc

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but if I have to know the names before hand, it defeats the purpose.